# what could be the solution for this huge data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

See this is my schema

```
category
  ObjectId
  catId
  ... (other Attributes)

devices_installed
  ObjectId
  deviceId
  partNo
  Name
  Type
  when_installed (time-marker)
  installed_by
  ...
  catId

devices_main_activities
  ObjectId
  deviceId
  catId
  actities[{time,data,lat,long,name},{},{}...20]

devices_secondary_activities
  ObjectId
  deviceId
  catId
  actities[{time,some_data},{},{}.....20]
```

(There are lot of other Collections but those are really small, Category Collection is also a small collection may reach upto 5000 may be in 1 year.. but other three collections are huge)

Now this `devices_main_activities` and `devices_secondary_activities` have lot of documents and already have touched 12 million documents and its growing by a steady rate. (Each document in these two collection stores a time based activities but that cannot exceed 20 activities).

Now the problem is it is slowing down the query, mean query take about 10 sec to 30 second depending on the attribute or sub-attribute I'm querying for (if it's not a Index). And also suggest a good shard key, we haven't yet moved the database to Sharding Setup, but we will be moving in a month.

Comment: For suggesting a shard key, you should show more attributes that you are saving regarding the activities.

Comment: Okay let me Edit it..